# Can you use a Marshall single channel footswitch with a MG102FX 4-channel amp?

Tags: amplifiers

I have a four-channel MG102FX amp. Will a single-channel pedal work with it? Both are Marshall. Help, please! I just want to be able to go from clean to distortion.

Comment: Looking at [the user manual](http://www.marshallamps.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/mg15cfx-mg100hcfx-hbk3.pdf), it's hard to say what a single footswitch would do; it has a standard-looking 1/4" jack input, but the pedal pictures has four switches and a tuner.

Answer (score 1):

It will at least do something. One of the 4 channels will be triggered. Just test it out...

Comment: this assumes they have the same type of input to the amp. I used to have a four-button foot switch for a Gallien Krueger amp that used a five-pin-din connection.